# Using Apache, can I forward all the environment variables set via "SetEnv" in .htaccess files?

Tags: php, apache, http, fastcgi

I'm trying to use Apache as a proxy. When I do this via FCGI, environment variables set in .htaccess files via `SetEnv` are forwarded through the request context and can be loaded by the php processor as a `$_SERVER[]` variable. However, I want to use HTTP instead of FCGI. I'm wondering if there is still a way to capture the variables set in .htaccess files through the `SetEnv` method?

Comment: What do you mean by http instead of fcgi?

Comment: In my apache config file, I'm using `ProxyPass` instead of the way which was done before (`SetHandler proxy:fcgi`).

Comment: ProxyPass to what?  How are you serving php?

Comment: Serving php via PHP-FPM

Comment: OK.  So you're still serving through fcgi, I guess you're using mod_proxy_fcgi?  Your question has some confusing info in it but no I don't think mod_proxy_fcgi will pass env variables.  What would you be defining in .htaccess anyways?

Comment: Not exactly... It's sort of strange but our goal is to forward using HTTP via mod_proxy and then converting the HTTP to FCGI and sending that to PHP-FPM. Currently we don't use mod_proxy_fcgi and instead use a method called SetHandler and set a the proxy there (not exactly sure how that works, but it's what is currently being done). At the moment, when we set an environment variable in .htaccess, this can be read by PHP. I want to know if similar behavior can be achieved using mod_proxy or any other method where Apache forwards HTTP

Comment: So you have two different http servers in the request chain?  Both apache?

Comment: Yes... But the second server is not apache. It is something we set up that strictly handles PHP processing using PHP-FPM

Comment: I couldn't find anything on automatically forwarding environmental variables.  You can manually define headers to forward via the proxy.  Serverfault would be a better place than SO for something like this.  Personally, I'd think there is probably a better place than .htaccess to define whatever variable you are setting.